# Retrieving data from table with multiple row

Tags: laravel

I am currently having trouble retrieving the data from a table based on their id. Here the $`content` will pluck multiple ids from the table. When retrieving the `ModuleDevelopment` table, it retrieves all of the data without organizing by their id. What should I do to separate the status based on their id?

```
$content = ModuleListing::where('sme_role', $selectedRole)
    ->get()->pluck('mit_id');

$stats = ModuleDevelopment::whereIn('mdev_mit_id', $content)
    ->orderBY('mdev_mit_id','desc')->get()->pluck('mdev_status');
```

[result of $stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Iva.png)
[result of $content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1XFX.png)

Comment: Can you try this? `dd($stats = ModuleDevelopment::whereIn('mdev_mit_id', [1, 21])->orderBY('mdev_mit_id','desc')->get()->pluck('mdev_status'));`. What does it show?

Comment: You obviously have a relation going on here. why not use it.

Comment: @fufubrocat it shows the same result as the first one but the "incomplete" is on top meanwhile the others are "complete

Comment: @MichaelMano im currently confused how to do the relations, i am kinda new to laravel

Comment: @Tina is your goal to get an array output of just `1 => 'complete'` and `21 => 'incomplete'`?

Comment: remove the `get()` before `pluck('mdev_status')`

Comment: @fufubrocat yes yes, because if all status of 1 is complete then it will display complete, if not, then it will state incomplete

Comment: @FarhanIbnWahid I have tried and it still is not separating according to its id, the output is the same as how fufubrocat gave the code

Comment: Hello, just checking if you were already able to solve this?

Comment: @fufubrocat apparently, no, i tried to add other codes but still to no avail. 
foreach ($stats as $stat) {
               
                    if ($stat->mdev_status === 'complete') {
                        $status = 'Complete';
                    } elseif ($stat->mdev_status === 'incomplete') {
                        $status = 'Incomplete';
                    } else {
                        $status = 0;
                    }

                }

Comment: If your goal is to have the output of  `1 => 'complete'` and `21 => 'incomplete'`, I dont think that's possible because the numbers `1` and `21` here are considered an array index. What would happen is you'll be getting an output of  `0 => 'complete'` and `1 => 'incomplete'`.

Comment: @fufubrocat - i will try to do some more codes to adjust, will sure to tell if I have got the solution. Thank  you very much for your time to try and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update of the coding I previously had trouble with, the main issue was to organize the status of each module development based on their ID,
therefore, the code I had was

this was at my controller:

```
 $moduleDev = ModuleDevelopment::select('mdev_mit_id','mdv_sts')
                        ->whereIn('mdev_mit_id', $content)
                        ->orderBY('mdev_mit_id', 'asc')
                        ->get();
```

and this is what was on my blade.php

```
@foreach($moduleDev as $modDev)
   @if($listing->mit_id == $modDev->mdev_mit_id)
      @if($modDev->mdv_sts == 'complete'  )
         {{'Complete'}}
      @elseif($modDev->mdv_sts == 'incomplete')
         {{'Incomplete'}}
     
      @endif
   @endif
@endforeach
```

I hope it is right and helpful for other people.